# How to get a SourceReader to decompress frames and send them to a Direct3D9 texture?

Tags: video, direct3d, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

I am trying to get a MediaFoundation SourceReader to read an H.264 video file, and render the frames to some Direct3D textures so I can them render them as I wish with Direct3D.

I'm using SharpDX, but the principles are of course the same as native code.

As I understand it, the general data flow should be like this:

1. A `SourceReader` reads and decodes the video using `SourceReader.ReadSample()`
2. A `VideoProcessor` (from `IDirect3DDeviceManager9`) transfers the frame to a Direct3D9 surface using `VideoProcessor.VideoProcessBlt()`
3. My Direct3D9 renderer uses the surface to render the frame however I want onto the screen

If this is how it's supposed to work, I've pretty much have it figured out, and almost running.

I was able to decode frames from H.264 to X8R8G8B8 by setting `EnableVideoProcessing` when I created my `SourceReader`:

```
MediaFactory.CreateAttributes(mediaAttributes, 0);
mediaAttributes.Set(SourceReaderAttributeKeys.EnableVideoProcessing, 1);
MediaFactory.CreateSourceReaderFromURL(url, mediaAttributes, SourceReader);
```

And by setting the media type subtype to the X8R8G8B8 GUID for the video stream:

```
VideoSubType = currentMediaType.Get<Guid>(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.Subtype);
UnpackLong(currentMediaType.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameSize), out VideoWidth, out VideoHeight);
UnpackLong(currentMediaType.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameRate), out VideoFrameRateNumerator, out VideoFrameRateDenominator);
VideoInterlaceMode = (VideoInterlaceMode)(uint)(currentMediaType.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.InterlaceMode));

MediaFactory.CreateMediaType(outputMediaType);
outputMediaType.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.MajorType, MediaTypeGuids.Video);
outputMediaType.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.Subtype, VideoSubType);
outputMediaType.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameSize.Guid, PackLong(VideoWidth, VideoHeight));
outputMediaType.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameRate.Guid, PackLong(VideoFrameRateNumerator, VideoFrameRateDenominator));
outputMediaType.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.InterlaceMode.Guid, VideoInterlaceMode);
outputMediaType.Set(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.PixelAspectRatio.Guid, PackLong(1, 1));

SourceReader.SetCurrentMediaType(streamIndex, outputMediaType);
```

Later, when I call `ReadSample()`, I am getting video and audio samples, so I think the decoding process is working fine.

However, in order to get `VideoProcessor`-compatible frames, I need to create my `SourceReader`, setting the `D3DManager` on the media attributes, and also make sure DXVA is not disabled:

```
mediaAttributes.Set(SourceReaderAttributeKeys.D3DManager, VideoConnector.GetManager());
mediaAttributes.Set(SourceReaderAttributeKeys.DisableDxva, 0);
```

The problem is that `CreateSourceReaderFromURL` fails (0x80070057) when I set both `EnableVideoProcessing` and `D3DManager`. This is implied by the `D3DManager` [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375772%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> You would not set this attribute if [...] you are getting compressed video from the source reader. In that case, the source reader does not create a decoder.

Supposing I could decode the frames later (perhaps with a `VideoDecoder`?), I tried removing `EnableVideoProcessing` and just leave `D3DManager` and `DisableDxva`, but in that case, it's `ReadSample` that fails (0xC00D36B4) even before I get a chance to use the data in the sample.

So how am I supposed to read, decode and send my frames to the Direct3D surface?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the MFCaptureToFile sample project in the SDK, there it configures the source reader to output the frames in the desired format. The method ConfigureSourceReader() does that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use SharpDX, but in native D3D, if you want to decode video with DXVA, you should
set `MF_SOURCE_READER_DISABLE_DXVA` to false and enable `MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_ADVANCED_VIDEO_PROCESSING` instead of `MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_VIDEO_PROCESSING`. Maybe you can try it.