# How to capture frames from a webcam with SharpDX

Tags: c#, webcam, sharpdx

I'm trying to implement a webcam capture app which should take still frames, display them on the screen and save to the disk.

Since I'm using SharpDX already to capture the screen, I thought it would be nice to use that library. I was not sure if SharpDX had any video capture capabilities, so I started searching and found parts of what it looks like a webcam capture prototype:

```
var attributes = new MediaAttributes(1);
attributes.Set<Guid>(CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceType, CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceTypeVideoCapture.Guid);
var activates = MediaFactory.EnumDeviceSources(attributes);

var dic = new Dictionary<string, Activate>();
foreach (var activate in activates)
{
    var uid = activate.Get(CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceTypeVidcapSymbolicLink);
    dic.Add(uid, activate);
}

var camera = dic.First().Value;
```

It outputs `camera` with a strange uid. I'm not sure if it's correct.

What I am supposed to do after this?

### Edit

I got this code kind of working. I still don't understand why the output is strange.

```
var attributes = new MediaAttributes(1);
attributes.Set(CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceType.Guid, CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceTypeVideoCapture.Guid);

var mediaSource = MediaFactory.EnumDeviceSources(attributes)[0].ActivateObject<MediaSource>();
mediaSource.CreatePresentationDescriptor(out var presentationDescriptor);

var reader = new SourceReader(mediaSource);
var mediaTypeIndex = 0;

int width, height;

using (var mt = reader.GetNativeMediaType(0, mediaTypeIndex))
{
    UnpackLong(mt.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameSize), out  width, out  height);
    UnpackLong(mt.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.FrameRate), out var frameRateNumerator, out var frameRateDenominator);
    UnpackLong(mt.Get(MediaTypeAttributeKeys.PixelAspectRatio), out var aspectRatioNumerator, out var aspectRatioDenominator);
}

var sample = reader.ReadSample(SourceReaderIndex.AnyStream, SourceReaderControlFlags.None, out var readStreamIndex, out var readFlags, out var timestamp);

if (sample == null)
    sample = reader.ReadSample(SourceReaderIndex.AnyStream, SourceReaderControlFlags.None, out readStreamIndex, out readFlags, out timestamp);


var sourceBuffer = sample.GetBufferByIndex(0); // sample.ConvertToContiguousBuffer();
var sourcePointer = sourceBuffer.Lock(out var maxLength, out var currentLength);

var data = new byte[sample.TotalLength];
Marshal.Copy(sourcePointer, data, 0, sample.TotalLength);

var newData = new byte[width * 4 * height];

var partWidth = width / 4;
var partHeight = height / 3;

for (var i = 0; i < sample.TotalLength; i += 4)
{
    //X8R8B8G8 -> BGRA = 4
    newData[i] = data[i + 3];
    newData[i + 1] = data[i + 2];
    newData[i + 2] = data[i + 1];
    newData[i + 3] = 255; //data[i];
}

//var source = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, data, ((width * 24 + 31) / 32) * 4);
var source = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, newData, width * 4);

sourceBuffer.Unlock();
sourceBuffer.Dispose();
```

The output image is this ([I was showing a color spectrum to my webcam](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Spectrum.2400.1800.S.G.png)):

[image: Spectrum]

The image is repeating 4 times, each part has a grayscale image and a color version with half the height.
Two thirds of the image is transparent.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624688/how-to-get-a-sourcereader-to-decompress-frames-and-send-them-to-a-direct3d9-text) which mentions **MFCaptureToFile sample project in the SDK**.  Maybe that can help.  Looks like you're assuming BGRA, but what's shown sure looks like a different color format.

Answer (score 1):

your output is NV12, here's some sample code to convert nv12 to rgb

```
    unsafe private static void TransformImage_NV12(IntPtr pDest, int lDestStride, IntPtr pSrc, int lSrcStride, int dwWidthInPixels, int dwHeightInPixels)
    {
        uint imageWidth = (uint)dwWidthInPixels;
        uint widthHalf = imageWidth / 2;
        uint imageHeight = (uint)dwHeightInPixels;

        byte* nv12Data = (byte*)pSrc;
        byte* rgbData = (byte*)pDest;

        uint dataSize = imageWidth * imageHeight * 3;

        for (uint y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
        {
            for (uint x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
            {
                uint xEven = x & 0xFFFFFFFE;
                uint yEven = y & 0xFFFFFFFE;
                uint yIndex = y * imageWidth + x;
                uint cIndex = imageWidth * imageHeight + yEven * widthHalf + xEven;

                byte yy = nv12Data[yIndex];
                byte cr = nv12Data[cIndex + 0];
                byte cb = nv12Data[cIndex + 1];

                uint outputIndex = (dataSize - (y * imageWidth + x) * 3) - 3;

                rgbData[outputIndex + 0] = (byte)Math.Min(Math.Max((yy + 1.402 * (cr - 128)), 0), 255);
                rgbData[outputIndex + 1] = (byte)Math.Min(Math.Max((yy - 0.344 * (cb - 128) - 0.714 * (cr - 128)), 0), 255);
                rgbData[outputIndex + 2] = (byte)Math.Min(Math.Max((yy + 1.772 * (cb - 128)), 0), 255);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying to you. I'm getting an image flipped vertically. And BTW, it's BGR, not RGB (but I want to work with BGR anyway).

Comment: The `MediaType` is MJPEG. If I switch to NV12 (by selecting other format within the stream), I only get a few bytes in the sample.